# Split string with negative digits

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
0:@AA-1:@BB--2:@CC
```

The minus separator is used to split each block of "index:string". Currently I'm trying to handle also negative values such **-2:@CC**
How to split correctly that string?

Comment: You can not use some other separator such as # or comma? Since - is going to be used for negative number as well as separator, the parsing logic will be tricky. It will be simpler to to use distinguishable separator if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Regex.Split with pattern `(?<=\w)-`

```
var input = @"0:@AA-1:@BB--2:@CC";
var pattern = @"(?<=\w)-";
            
string[] result = Regex.Split(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Here is the result of Split method with this pattern:

```
'0:@AA', '1:@BB', '-2:@CC'
```